# jquery ui bottonset() doesnt work

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

Im trying to widgetize a group of radio buttons with jquery ui.

jquery and jquery-ui is loaded from googleapis. I've uploaded a ui theme and included the css file in the header.
This is how I call the buttonset function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#color").buttonset();
});
</script>
```

And this is the markup

```
<form>
    <div id="color">
        <input type="radio" class="color" id="color1" name="color" value="green" checked="checked" /><label for="color1">Gr&oslash;n</label>
        <input type="radio" class="color" id="color2" name="color" value="red" /><label for="color2">R&oslash;d</label>
        <input type="radio" class="color" id="color3" name="color" value="white" /><label for="color3">Hvid</label>
    </div>
</form>
```

The ui script only adds the ui-buttonset class to the #color container. But the radios wont convert into stylish buttons. Can someone see what im missing?

Comment: Are you using an old stylesheet, from jQuery UI 1.7 by chance?

Comment: No, its freshly downloaded from the theme roller app

Comment: @Greenie - It sounds like your CSS isn't getting included, double check the path?

Comment: The path is good. The #color container gets some margin applied from the css file

Comment: And stuff like tabs, accordion and other widgets works perfect on the same page. Only button() and buttonset() doesnt work. Im baffled

Comment: maybe you got same id's by chance?... try changing it to class just to check...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bugger, after trying redownloading and uploading, isolating, proofreading and a few wasted hours - the original set up is working... still dont know what I was doing wrong :(

edit: Ok figured it out. It was the google hosted versions of jquery an jquery-ui that diddnt play nice with the themeroller theme. Works as intended with the bundled local versions.